# Emacs tree edit

Tags: emacs, tree, treeview, mode

Some times I have tasks to create text tree, for example:

```
         (*) Root1 (1)-┐
                          ├ step1 (create some) (2)
                          ├ step2 (create some other type) (3)-------┐
                          |                                 (*) Root2 (8)
                          ├ step3 make some action(4)                 ├ 
                                                            step1 create obj (9)
```

And accordingly I try to find some emacs modes to edit text tree, but find nothing.

There is a lot of tree for show files and directories and other structures.
(*neotree*, *ztree* and other ...)

Also there is *artist-mode* that can help create ascii art. Tree can be doing with it.

But is there extension to edit tree with ability to add/delete/edit nodes ?
It is not required to edit text directly, ability to create not text tree and 
export it to text also will be good.

In my opinion there is should be something created with such things as:
*Hierarchy.el* (https://emacs.cafe/emacs/guest-post/2017/06/26/hierarchy.html).

Comment: I once was one of the creators of [TrEd](http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/tred/) which can edit trees in a GUI, not text. It's kind of hard to install nowadays, though.

Comment: Thank you, but I try to find solution for emacs.

Comment: Can you use org-mode outlines ?  You can apply some  org-mode customization,  use regex to convert back and forth your original data.

Comment: I assume, you mean something as https://github.com/jplindstrom/emacs-org-transform-tree-table. Yes, it as good idea and useful in some cases, but it is wanted some more intuitive and convenient.